# <FormSettings> isn't loading up on Outlook mobile app

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to create a `<FormSettings>` based outlook add-in which will NOT look like a button but a link which will open up as a form.

I'm facing some issues related to outlook mobile add-in. `<FormSettings>` isn't loading up on mobile add-in list.

I tried to add `<MobileFormFactor>` and `<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">` but because of this I had to add `VersionOverridesV1_1` & `VersionOverridesV1_0` not only this I had to add `<DesktopFormFactor>` in `VersionOverridesV1_0`.

Not my add-in isn't loading up on outlook mobile app but I can see it in the add-in list.

Any tips what i"m doing wrong or where I can find relevant help or a sample code which works around `<FormSettings>` .

Comment: Hello Sagar, Can you confirm you are trying to launch your add-in from the Outlook Mobile app for iOS or Android rather than accessing Outlook through a browser on a mobile device? Our documentation for the Outlook mobile app for iOS and Android can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-mobile-addins. Could you also provide a screenshot of what you are seeing? This will help us better understand what you are experiencing.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying on Android iOS applications and not on the browser